# Php build array from comma separated array values

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have a array with some array values contains multiple values separated by comma as shown below.

```
    $a  =  array(
              '0' => 't1,t2',
              '1' => 't3',
              '2' => 't4,t5'
           );
```

I need output in the following format.

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => t1
        [1] => t2
        [2] => t3
        [3] => t4
        [4] => t5
    )
```

This is how tried and getting the results. Is there any other alternative way without looping twice.

```
    $arr_output = array();

    foreach($a as $val)
    {
        $temp = explode(',', $val);
        foreach($temp as $v)
        {
            $arr_output[] = $v;
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: post your code as well what you have tried?

Comment: @orangetime No need to use loops here, you can get desired output by using predefined php array functions. check my answer below.

Comment: @prudhvi259, Thank you very much. Your solution is very simple.

Comment: Earlier question which asks for more processing than needed for this task. [Isolate comma-separated values, remove duplicates and empty values, then sort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24385884/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert your old array in to string like,
`$old_array =  array
    (
       "t1,t2",
        "t3",
        "t4,t5"
    );`
to 

`$string = implode(",", $old_array);`
Now
`echo $string;`
 gives a string with coma separator now using this you get desired array

```
$new_array = explode(",", $string);
```

If you print this you will get

```
Array(
[0] => t1
[1] => t2
[2] => t3
[3] => t4
[4] => t5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = Array (
        "t1,t2",
        "t3",
        "t4,t5"
    );

$splitted = array_map (function ($a) {return explode (",", $a);}, $array);
$arr = array_reduce($splitted, function ($a, $b) {
     return array_merge($a, (array) $b);
}, []);    

print_r ($arr);
```

First of all, you split every string by coma. You get an array of arrays.
To merge them, you call a merging function, such as the one in the example with array_reduce.

Comment: This is way too much processing.  `explode(',', implode(',', $array))` is all that is needed.